# How to get count of a particular row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table that contain Id,Date and Status i.e open/close
i just want a result in sql that contain month wise open,close and total count of Id's
e.g In Jan open count 15,close count 5 and total count 20

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: can u give me example

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: sql server engine

Comment: give your initial and final output data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RollUp() and Group By as below:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,     
        DATENAME(MONTH,[Date]) AS [MonthName],          
        Status
    FROM @tblTest
)
SELECT
    [MonthName],
    [Status],
    StatusCount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MonthName,
        CASE ISNULL(Status,'') WHEN '' THEN 'Total' ELSE Status END AS Status,          
        Count(Status) AS StatusCount                        
    FROM T
    GROUP BY ROLLUP([MonthName],[Status])
)X
WHERE X.MonthName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY X.[MonthName],X.[Status]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If required data in single row by month then apply PIVOT

Comment: Your ans is absolute correct and is working for me but can u just elaborate your ans...

Comment: I think you very well familiar with group by. Additional there are RollUp and Cube functionality which add extra row to add your group summary/group footer. Read More : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets

Comment: Also look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053471/understanding-the-differences-between-cube-and-rollup

Answer (score -1):

```
select year(date), month(date), 
       sum(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) as open_count,
       sum(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed_count,
       count(*) as total_count
from your_table
group by year(date), month(date)
```