# how to change SQL query by not using union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, union-all

here is the table

```
table table_nm(
ID
,AA
,BB
)
```

and, here is my query that i want to change

```
select
COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS ID_AA
, AA as AA_1
, 0 as ID_BB
, 0 as BB_1 
from table_nm
group by
AA

UNION ALL

select
  0 as ID_AA
, 0 as AA_1
, COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS ID_BB
, BB as BB_1
from table_nm
group by
BB
```

---

how to change that query with out UNION ALL??

Comment: Hi, I don't know what is your exact requirement. Please take look into these links which may be helpful:- 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053471/understanding-the-differences-between-cube-and-rollup


https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What's wrong with `UNION ALL`?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. You can remove those redundant parentheses to make things clearer. (I.e. `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)`.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT L.ID_AA, L.AA_1, R.ID_BB, R.BB_1 
FROM ( 
    select
    COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS ID_AA
    , AA as AA_1
    , 0 as ID_BB
    , 0 as BB_1 
    from table_nm
    group by AA
) AS L
FULL JOIN
(
    select
      0 as ID_AA
    , 0 as AA_1
    , COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS ID_BB
    , BB as BB_1
    from table_nm
    group by BB
) AS R ON L.AA_1 = R.BB_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx) and [GROUPING_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql) like this

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN grouping_ID(tn.AA) = 0 THEN tn.AA ELSE 0 END AS AA_1,
       CASE WHEN grouping_ID(tn.AA) = 0 THEN count(DISTINCT(tn.ID)) ELSE 0 END AS ID_AA,
       CASE WHEN grouping_ID(tn.BB) = 0 THEN tn.BB ELSE 0 END AS BB_1,
       CASE WHEN grouping_ID(tn.BB) = 0 THEN count(DISTINCT(tn.ID)) ELSE 0 END  AS ID_BB
FROM @table_nm tn
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((tn.AA),(tn.BB))
```

See demo here  http://rextester.com/SWN42877

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use following query.

```
SELECT t1.AA_1,
       t1.ID_AA,
       t2.BB_1,
       t2.ID_BB
FROM
(
    SELECT AA AS AA_1,
           COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS ID_AA
    FROM table_nm
    GROUP BY AA
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT BB AS BB_1,
           COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS ID_BB
    FROM table_nm
    GROUP BY BB
) t2 ON t1.AA_1 = t2.BB_1;
```

In order to get 0 for null values you can use `COALESCE()` (i.e. Standard ANSI SQL), `IFNULL`, `ISNULL` or `NVL` functions for MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle respectively.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. You can remove those redundant parentheses to make things clearer. (I.e. `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)`)

Comment: `COALESCE()` is the general function to return first non-null argument.